# Undefined offset error in php?

Tags: php, android, openstreetmap, offset

**Hello everyone!**

I am trying to parse a JSON/XML from OSM (Overpass Turbo) into php and trying to get the speedlimit value. I am able to get the value, but before that there are some errors

**"Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\android_connect\test-osm.php on line 44"**, which is this code `if ($temp[1]=="maxspeed")`

*What I am trying to is:*

First: After getting the result from OSM, I am breaking the response with "**<**" tag into an array called 'resultArr'

Second: Then, I am breaking the 'resultArr' with " **"** " tags into an array called "temp".

Given below is the php file:

```
<?php
//$lat  = isset($_GET['lat']) ? floatval($_GET['lat']) :  "";
//$lng = isset($_GET['lng']) ? floatval($_GET['lng']) :  "";

$lat  = 24.883968;
$lng = 55.544899;

//$latm = -0.00015 + $lat;
$latm = 54.580460;
//echo $latm. "\n";
//$latp = 0.00015 + $lat;
$latp = 54.580860;
//echo $latp. "\n";
//$lngm = -0.00015 + $lng;
$lngm = 24.326180;
//echo $lngm. "\n";
//$lngp = 0.00015 + $lng;
$lngp = 24.336580;
//echo $lngp;

$json_url = 'http://overpass.osm.rambler.ru/cgi/interpreter';

$data = '<query type="way"> <bbox-query s="' . $lngm . '" w="' . $latm . '" n="' . $lngp . '" e="' . $latp . '"/> <!--this is auto-completed with the current map view coordinates.--> </query> <print/>';

$ch = curl_init( $json_url );

$options = array(
CURLOPT_POST => true,
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/json') ,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
);

curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$result =  curl_exec($ch);

$resultArr = explode("<",$result); //Array without "<" tags!

foreach ($resultArr as $val) {
    $temp = explode('"', $val); //Array without """ tags!
    //print_r ($temp);

//Trying to check if temp[1] is maxspeed, then get the value of temp[3]...
            if ($temp[1]=="maxspeed")
            $speedlimit=$temp[3];
    }
    echo $speedlimit;

    ?>
```

**Note: the comments in this are just for checking purposes...**

I know I am doing some small mistake, I hope someone could tell me what wrong am I doing or guide me to the right direction!!

**Thanks alot!**

Comment: @mmd - any idea about it?? this is part of that question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that not all ways contain a tag called maxspeed therefore you also need to check if

```
isset($temp[1]) && $temp[1] == "maxspeed"
```

what you could also do is use simplexml like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);

foreach ($xml->way as $i) {
    foreach ($i->tag as $tag) {
        if ($tag['k'] == "maxspeed") {
            $maxspeed = $tag['v'];
            break;
        }
    }
}

echo $maxspeed;
```

Comment: if I use the second option that you suggested, so how can I use the isset function if there is no max-speed?? I'll be checking $xml array?

Comment: In the second option you dont have to use the isset

Comment: aha! So, if there is no max-speed tag in the whole response, I should add something in the else part, so that it doesn't crash..?

Comment: nope, the maxspeed will be null in that case. It wont crash

Comment: hmm!! right.. thanks alot again.. this was very helpful and useful for me..!!

Answer (score 1):

Syntax error, maybe? Missing curly brackets for IF statement?

```
if ($temp[1]=="maxspeed")
$speedlimit=$temp[3];
```

should be :

```
if ($temp[1]=="maxspeed") {
$speedlimit=$temp[3];
}
```